# JTable show JTextFiled search result

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTextFiled and JTable that read data from text file.

I want to add a keyListener to my JTextFiled that when enter a number ' program should search my textfile and show lines that start with that number on my JTable.

My Text File:

```
26     thired     62     Yes
29     sixth     92     No
35     vff     53     No
33     oll     36     No
38     koole     86     No
```

For example, When i write "3" in textfield, my JTable should display this three lines on own:

```
35     vff     53     No
33     oll     36     No
38     koole     86     No
```

My Code:

```
public class BookPage extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

private AllBooks bookModel;
private JTable bTabel;
JTextField tf1;


public BookPage(){
    bookModel=new AllBooks();
    bTabel=new JTable(bookModel);

    tf1=new JTextField(20);
    tf1.addKeyListener(this);

    JPanel panel= new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scroolpane=new JScrollPane(bTabel);
    panel.add(tf1);
    panel.add(scroolpane);
    this.setContentPane(panel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(300, 60, 800, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    new BookPage().setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    String line=tf1.getText().trim();
    SearchBook(line);

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

public void SearchBook(String Bid){
    File f=new File("AllBookRecords.txt");
    try{
        FileReader Bfr=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader Bbr=new BufferedReader(Bfr);
        String bs;
        while( (bs=Bbr.readLine()) != null ){
            String[] Ust=bs.split("     ");
            String id=Ust[0];
            String Bname=Ust[1];
            String Bdate=Ust[2];
            String borrowS=Ust[3];
            if(id.equals(Bid.trim())){
               bTabel.setValueAt(Bname, 10, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class AllBooks extends AbstractTableModel{
BookInformation Binfos1=new BookInformation();

String[] Bcol=new String[]{"Id","Name","Date","Borrow Status"};
ArrayList<BookInformation> Bdata=new ArrayList<BookInformation>();

public AllBooks(){
    try{
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("AllBookRecords.txt");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;

        while( (line=br.readLine()) != null){
            Bdata.add(initializeBookInfos(line));
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){

    }
}

public static BookInformation initializeBookInfos(String myLine){
    BookInformation Binit=new BookInformation();
    String[] bookCellArray=myLine.split("     ");
    Binit.setBookID(bookCellArray[0]);
    Binit.setBookName(bookCellArray[1]);
    Binit.setBookDate(bookCellArray[2]);
    Binit.setBorrowStatus(bookCellArray[3]);
    return Binit;
}
public void RemoveMyRow(int row){
    if(RemoveBookFromFile(row)){
       Bdata.remove(row);
      fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }
}

public boolean RemoveBookFromFile(int index){

    File Mf=new File("AllBookRecords.txt");
    File Tf=new File("Boutput.txt");
    try{
        BufferedReader Ubr=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Mf));
        PrintWriter Bpw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Tf));
        String line;
        while( (line=Ubr.readLine()) != null ){
            if(line.trim().length() == 0){
                continue;
            }
            if(!line.startsWith(String.valueOf(getValueAt(index, 0)))){
                Bpw.println(line);
            }
        }
        Bpw.close();
        Ubr.close();
        Mf.delete();
        Tf.renameTo(Mf);
        return true;
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
        return false;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
          return false;
    }
}

public void AddRow(BookInformation bookinfo){
    if(WriteBooktofile(bookinfo.toString())){
        Bdata.add(bookinfo);
        fireTableRowsInserted(Bdata.size()-1, Bdata.size()-1);
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable Add To File"+bookinfo.getBookName());
    }
}

public boolean WriteBooktofile(String bookc){
    try{
        File f=new File("AllBookRecords.txt");

            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(bookc);
            bw.close();
            return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col){
    return Bcol[col];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    if(Bdata !=null){
    return Bdata.size();
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return Bcol.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    BookInformation binfo=Bdata.get(rowIndex);
    Object value;

    switch(columnIndex){

        case 0:
            value=binfo.getBookID();
            break;
        case 1:
            value=binfo.getBookName();
            break;
        case 2:
            value=binfo.getBookDate();
            break;
        case 3:
            value=binfo.getBorrowStatus();
            break;
        default :
            value="...";  
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class BookInformation {

private String BookName;
private String BookDate;
private String BookID;
private String BorrowStatus;

public String getBookName() {
    return BookName;
}

public void setBookName(String book_name) {
    this.BookName = book_name;
}

public String getBookDate() {
    return BookDate;
}


public void setBookDate(String book_date) {
    this.BookDate = book_date;
}


public String getBookID() {
    return BookID;
}

public void setBookID(String Book_id) {
    this.BookID = Book_id;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return BookID + "     " + BookName+ "     "
            + BookDate +"     "+ BorrowStatus + "\n";
}

public String getBorrowStatus() {
    return BorrowStatus;
}


public void setBorrowStatus(String borrowStat) {
    BorrowStatus = borrowStat;
}

}
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Please post also BookInformation class

Comment: @FestusTamakloe I add  BookInformation class

Comment: My first recommendation is to avoid key listeners and use a DocumentFilter. My second recommendation is to have the text file loaded in memory if you can, or stored in light in memory database, it will make it quicker a simpler to search. There is also a concern with block the EDT when search for the users input.  At worst case, you will have to search the entire contents of the file for each key stroke, this could cause the UI to stop responding to the user. If possible, it would be better to have the file indexed in some way (assuming the numbers are unsorted) so you can do a quick look up

Comment: I guess that next question is - what's not working?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've previously put a search button, but one of my friends said that this way is better
I think it will slow down the program?
Is this true?

Comment: If you are reading from the file on each key stroke, then yes, it will slow down the program.

Comment: No , now my program search after press search button

Comment: But, just want to learn this way - if this way is bad in your opinion ' i don't use this way

Comment: @Sajjad-HiFriend i get it. just look at my post

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi, I want to tell me some sites that i send my whole project and then it Evaluation by java master programmers.  Is there such sites?

Comment: @Sajjad-HiFriend I'd suggest something like programmers exchange

Comment: @MadProgrammer when i put my project jar file with some neede files in rar file in codereview.stackexchange.com , there is no help!

Comment: My question link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/sample-library-management-system-application-in-java

Comment: Users say that i should put my projects codes! ut my project have about 12 class.

Comment: Can you see my project and tell me it's defects and Flaws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make some changes on your nativ code to make it works. Please note that i have not check the hole code of his functionality.

I use

```
 @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            String line = tf1.getText().trim();
            SearchBook(line);
        }
```

instead of `public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}` because it doesn't transmit the first value

Your old BookPage looks now as

```
public class BookPage extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private AllBooks bookModel;

    private JTable bTabel;

    JTextField tf1;

    public BookPage() {
        bookModel = new AllBooks();
        bTabel = new JTable(bookModel);

        tf1 = new JTextField(20);
        tf1.addKeyListener(this);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scroolpane = new JScrollPane(bTabel);
        panel.add(tf1);
        panel.add(scroolpane);
        this.setContentPane(panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(300, 60, 800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BookPage().setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        String line = tf1.getText().trim();
        SearchBook(line);
    }

    public void SearchBook(String bid) {
        List<BookInformation> filtedRows = new ArrayList<BookInformation>();
        try {
            InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("AllBookRecords.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
            String bs;
            while((bs = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                BookInformation information = new BookInformation();
                String[] Ust = bs.split("\\t");
                information.setBookID(Ust[0]);
                information.setBookName(Ust[1]);
                information.setBookDate(Ust[2]);
                information.setBorrowStatus(Ust[3]);
                if(information.getBookID().equals(bid) || information.getBookID().startsWith(bid)) {
                    filtedRows.add(information);
                }
            }
            if(!filtedRows.isEmpty()) {
                      //remove old rows
                for(int i = bookModel.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    bookModel.RemoveMyRow(i);
                }
                     //add new rows
                for(BookInformation bookInformation : filtedRows) {
                    bookModel.AddRow(bookInformation);
                }
            }
            bookModel.fireTableDataChanged();

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

the major changes are done in `public void SearchBook(String bid) {}` if some is not clear feel free to ask me.

In your AllBooks just a little change

```
public class AllBooks extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    BookInformation Binfos1 = new BookInformation();

    String[] bCol = new String[] { "Id", "Name", "Date", "Borrow Status" };

    ArrayList<BookInformation> bData = new ArrayList<BookInformation>();

    public AllBooks() {
        try {
            InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("AllBookRecords.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                bData.add(initializeBookInfos(line));
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {

        }
    }

    public static BookInformation initializeBookInfos(String myLine) {
        BookInformation Binit = new BookInformation();
        String[] bookCellArray = myLine.split("\\t");
        Binit.setBookID(bookCellArray[0]);
        Binit.setBookName(bookCellArray[1]);
        Binit.setBookDate(bookCellArray[2]);
        Binit.setBorrowStatus(bookCellArray[3]);
        return Binit;
    }

    public void RemoveMyRow(int row) {
        if(RemoveBookFromFile(row)) {
            bData.remove(row);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        }
    }

    public boolean RemoveBookFromFile(int index) {

        File Mf = new File("AllBookRecords.txt");
        File Tf = new File("Boutput.txt");
        try {
            BufferedReader Ubr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Mf));
            PrintWriter Bpw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Tf));
            String line;
            while((line = Ubr.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.trim().length() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(!line.startsWith(String.valueOf(getValueAt(index, 0)))) {
                    Bpw.println(line);
                }
            }
            Bpw.close();
            Ubr.close();
            Mf.delete();
            Tf.renameTo(Mf);
            return true;
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e1) {
            return false;
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void AddRow(BookInformation bookinfo) {
        if(WriteBooktofile(bookinfo.toString())) {
            bData.add(bookinfo);
            fireTableRowsInserted(bData.size() - 1, bData.size() - 1);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable Add To File" + bookinfo.getBookName());
        }
    }

    public boolean WriteBooktofile(String bookc) {
        try {
            File f = new File("AllBookRecords.txt");

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(bookc);
            bw.close();
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return bCol[col];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        if(bData != null) {
            return bData.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return bCol.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        BookInformation binfo = bData.get(rowIndex);
        Object value;

        switch(columnIndex) {

            case 0:
                value = binfo.getBookID();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = binfo.getBookName();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = binfo.getBookDate();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = binfo.getBorrowStatus();
                break;
            default:
                value = "...";
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Now your AllBookRecords.txt is with tab separated (\t)

```
26  thired  62  Yes
29  sixth   92  No
35  vff 53  No
33  oll 36  No
38  koole   86  No
```

There is a several way to deal with this issue but i don't want to write every on my way but   try to make your code works with little changes

Comment: Thank you for post , is this way good? Or might slow down the program?

Comment: The way is good it'll not slow down your programm at all. we just show what we need otherwise no changes.

Answer (score 4):

Load all of the data into a JTable. Then use the table filtering feature to display only the rows you want. The **TableFilterDemo** from the [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section of the Swing tutorial is a working example that does this.